# Ubuntu Studio 11.04 My user account has dissappeared off of the log in gui

Tags: ubuntu, boot, gui

Turned on my linux box this evening- dual boot natty and studio - and discovered my login gui for studio was missing my user account name. As well as the desktop log in options (Ubuntu, ubuntu classic, etc) I got the log in options back up and available on the log in gui. But cannot for the life of me seem to get my account user name to do the same. I can log in via command line no problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

did you change your userid? Ubuntu only shows account with userID >= 1000. User accounts with ID < 1000 are not shown - but you can still type the username and log in.